# UISlider drag behaving strangely in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uislider

I have a strange problem with a UISlider I add to my view programmatically. I believe the issue was introduced with IOS7.

I am not using any custom images.

As the images below show, the track only appears when I begin to move it from my maximum value to my minimum value, it then disappears when I move it back.

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is the code I use to create the slider.

```
_brightnessSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(size.width * .45,
                                                               size.height * .78,
                                                               size.width * .4,
                                                               size.height * .1)];

[_brightnessSlider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
_brightnessSlider.minimumValue = 0.0;
_brightnessSlider.maximumValue = 1.0;
_brightnessSlider.continuous = YES;
_brightnessSlider.value = 1.0;
[_brightnessSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(changeBrightness:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[self.view addSubview:_brightnessSlider];
```

What could be causing this strange behaviour?

Comment: My slider is working fine.This issue is on device or simulator.

Comment: On the device. I cannot test in the simulator, as one of the libraries I have to use was not compiled for universal use.

Comment: I have run your code on device and that is working fine.I have just passed a fixed frame with your code like this"UISlider*  _brightnessSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,20,120,40)];"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in the code.. The issue is **"Min Track Tint colour"**. Your View background colour might be matching with MInTrackTintColor.

Use this:

```
[_brightnessSlider setMinimumTrackTintColor: [UIColor blueColor]];
```

Let me know if it does not solve your issue...

Comment: Awesome! I just set it to lightGreyColor and it appears.